# How do I use an "intersection" symbol in word?

Tags: keyboard

I desperately need to use the intersection symbol for a stats assignment but kind figure out how to do it in word.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Office 2011 on a recent OS X system, then its relatively easy to get a host of characters available.

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard tab and check **Show Keyboard and Character Viewers in menu bar**.

This will put a little icon, usually next to the Date/Time, in the menu bar.

From the new Menu Bar icon, choose **Show Character Viewer** and then select Math Symbols from the picker:

[image]

A host of symbols. Put the insertion point in your Word document, then double-click the symbol you need.

Comment: On Yosemite You can also make it form the keyboard shortcut: `⌘ CMD`+`⇧ SHIFT`+`Space bar` (It's systemwide).